# Can I merge two separate Xbox LIVE Gold accounts under one XBL Gold Family Pack?

Tags: xbox-360

Microsoft's Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack offers four Xbox LIVE Gold accounts for $100. Can I take two separate Xbox LIVE Gold accounts and make them both part of the same Xbox LIVE Gold Family Pack account? Microsoft has already said that a single account can be migrated into an Xbox Live Gold Family Pack account.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Microsoft, [Yes](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/JoinLive/FamilyPackFAQ).

To do so, you need to add the secondary accounts to the same console as the primary account holder. You then "activate" them into the Family Pack.  After that, you can recover those accounts onto different consoles, and etc.

Comment: I am excited by this news, however do you have a source?

Comment: Here is just one of the sources I found.  I'll try to find the others:  http://www.dailytech.com/100+Xbox+Live+Family+Plan+Coming+in+November/article18808.htm

Comment: I am very tempted to accept this answer, but I am suspicious as to whether that whole statement in the source was addressing the question of using accounts from the same Family Pack on different consoles.

Comment: @SAGE, Microsoft's FAQ does address this now: you can recover other accounts in a Family Pack onto different consoles within the same country.